# Stop Servlet response sending parameters back to page and forcing page reload

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, servlets

I am trying to get my servlet that I pass values from a form, to respond with some text that I want to output into an alert. The problem I am having is that after the alert box pops up the page reloads and gets redirected to the page + the parameters I passed to the servlet.

www.mysite.com/login.jsp -- redirects to

www.mysite.com/dashhome.jsp -- On this page I have a function that posts form data to a servlet.

The servlet only needs to return the string that is handled by and not redirect/cause the page to reload.

After I press save(post), I get my alert with the text string then the current page reloads with the parameters.

www.mysite.com/dashhome.jsp?pass-1=ertertert&passConf-1=ertertert&uid-1=1

Servlet: 
- I can see the values with the System.err.println and everything is coming into the servlet without issue. It would be cooler to pass the whole form instead of params but I dont know how to do that. The Servlet also returns the text to the javascript function.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
            throws ServletException, IOException {  
        dbVO dbvo = new dbVO();
        dbvo = dbBean.getSQLDBInfo();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String text = "";
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if((Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("accessType").toString())==1) && (System.currentTimeMillis()<(session.getLastAccessedTime() + session.getMaxInactiveInterval() * 1000)) ){
            String pass=request.getParameter("pass");  
            String confirmPass=request.getParameter("passConf"); 
            String uid=request.getParameter("uid");
            String adminID= session.getAttribute("ID").toString();
            System.err.println(pass);
            System.err.println(confirmPass);
            System.err.println(uid);
            System.err.println(adminID);
            text = "success";

        }else{
            text = "Session Expired";
        }
       response.getWriter().write(text);
    }  
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{  
                        doGet(request, response);
    }
```

Javascript:

```
function sendUpdate(id) { 
            $(document).ready(function(){
                    $.post("testurl",
                    {
                      pass: $('#pass-'+id).val(),
                      passConf: $('#passConf-'+id).val(),
                      uid:  $('#uid-'+id).val()
                    },
                    function(data,status){
                        switch(status) {
                        case 'Session Expired':
                            sessionExpired();
                            break;
                        default:
                            alert(status);
                    }
                    });
            });
        }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sooo, this Works fine I made my button a submit type instead of button and that was causing the post...